# mapply over two lists

Tags: r, list, apply

I recentely asked a question about using an `apply` function over two lists.  Each list is a list of data frames created by splitting a large dataframe. For each time the function runs I want to take vectors from the first element (a dataframe) in `mylist1` and some vectors from the first element (a dataframe) in `mylist2` and regress them against each other. Then move onto the next `mylist1` element and `mylist2` element.  Effectively the function takes two lists with the same number of elements and takes a pair (one from each list) and plays about with them.

I tried the following, but the results I get are not what I want:

```
a1<-c(1:5,rep(0,5))
a2<-c(1:5,10:6)
b2<-c(rep(100,5),rep(50,5))
z<-c(rep("part1",5),rep("part2",5))
df1<-data.frame(a1,z)
df2<-data.frame(a2,b2,z)

mylist1<-split(df1,z)
mylist2<-split(df2,z)


myfunction<-function(x,y) 
{

meana <- mean(x$a)
meanb <- mean(y$b)
model<-lm((x$a)~(y$a))
return(c(model$coefficients[2],meana=meana,meanb=meanb))
}

result <- mapply(myfunction,x=mylist,y=mylist2)

 #result
#        x   y
#y$a     1  -1
#meana   3   8
#meanb 100  50
```

What I want is:

```
#y$a     1   0   
#meana   3   0
#meanb   100 50


#e.g. the results in the first row are from lm((mylist1[[1]][,1])~(mylist2[[1]][,1]))  and lm((mylist1[[2]][,1])~(mylist2[[2]][,1]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code and got

```
> result <- mapply(myfunction,x=mylist1,y=mylist2)
> result
      part1 part2
y$a       1     0
meana     3     0
meanb   100    50
```

you have a typo

```
result <- mapply(myfunction,x=mylist,y=mylist2)
```

which I changed to

```
result <- mapply(myfunction,x=mylist1,y=mylist2)
```

maybe this is the issue